# How can I get pixel ARGB information from an image in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

Is there any way to get pixel RGB in silverlight? I have a PNG image which I'm going to find RGB and alpha of some pixels (I'm going to display ARGB of mouse position on image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like [Bitmap.GetPixel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel.aspx) (MSDN) would be a good place to start